Android back button not detected by react-native expo managed app
Problem:
When pressing the android back button, my app will immediately close on both my emulator and physical device. I want to detect the back button being pressed
EDIT: I have found that the BackHandler works within Expo Go but not within Development mode.
After simplifying my project, the back button is still not detected by the project as the alert is not shown (as added in App.js).
Before I consider refactoring and switching to expo router (which I'm not sure will fix this problem), I've decided to see if anyone might have encountered this issue in the past.

What I'm expecting:
I am trying to add functionality to control what happens when the user presses the android back button. For example, I would want an alert to pop up to confirm if the user wants to leave the app or not (as shown in App.js). Even a simple console log to detect that the user has pressed the back button would be great but this won't occur.
I have looked through the React Navigation documentation. However, I have not found a solution to this.
Android Bundled 115ms (C:\git\index.js) LOG  Workout screen is focused, adding back button listener
// App.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { BackHandler, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import Workout from './screens/Workout';
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store/store';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to go back?", [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => null,
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
      ]);
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Workout">
          <Stack.Screen name="Workout" component={Workout} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ReduxProvider>
  );
};

export default App;

// Workout.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Workout = () => {
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();

    useEffect(() => {
        const backAction = () => {
            console.log("Back button pressed in Workout screen");
            BackHandler.exitApp();  // Directly exit the app for testing
            return true;  // Prevent default behavior
        };

        if (isFocused) {
            console.log('Workout screen is focused, adding back button listener');
            const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);
            return () => {
                console.log('Workout screen is losing focus, removing back button listener');
                backHandler.remove();
            };
        }
    }, [isFocused]);  // Dependency array includes isFocused to re-attach listener when focus changes

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Workout Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default Workout;

// package.json
{
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "version": "0.2",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "devtools": "react-devtools",
    "test": "jest --detectOpenHandles",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^7.24.5",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^7.8.0",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "^6.7.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@redux-devtools/extension": "^3.3.0",
    "@redux-devtools/instrument": "^2.2.0",
    "@redux-devtools/serialize": "^0.4.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@sentry/cli": "^2.31.1",
    "@sentry/react-native": "~5.20.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "expo": "~50.0.17",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.11.1",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.6",
    "expo-dev-client": "~3.3.12",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.3",
    "expo-modules-core": "~1.11.13",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "firebase": "^10.12.2",
    "i18next": "^23.6.0",
    "i18next-react-native-async-storage": "^1.0.4",
    "normalizr": "^3.6.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-devtools": "^4.28.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^13.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1300.0",
    "react-native-crisp-chat-sdk": "^0.14.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.11.1",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-webview": "13.6.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "reselect": "^4.1.8",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "victory-native": "^36.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.3",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^16.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.1.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-expo": "~50.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16"
  },
  "private": true
}```


The code seems to work fine at least without ReduxProvider.

@user18309290 What did you do exactly the have it work without ReduxProvider? I commented out ReduxProvider from App.js and uninstalled react-redux. However, pressing back button did not invoke the Alert.
